# Oracle Count how much values in varchar

Tags: oracle, select, count

I'm testing with a query:

```
SELECT '-1,-2,-4,-6' "Verdunning"
  FROM DUAL
```

Now I need to know how much values are in the varchar: '-1,-2,-4,-6'. I want to have 4 back.
and when it is '-1,-2,-4,-6,-8' i need to get 5 back. How to do this in an oracle select statement?

Comment: Why do you have comma separated values in that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/20873)

```
SELECT LENGTH(Verdunning) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Verdunning, ',', '')) + 1
FROM (SELECT '-1,-2,-4,-6' AS Verdunning FROM DUAL) T
```

Comment: Did you ever try to test it?

Comment: Now this will work, but when i made the comment it was a different query. Lol... Also it is better to go with regexp than length

Answer (score 1):

find number of `,` then add 1 to get count

```
Select LEN(column) – LEN(REPLACE(column, ',', ''))+1 as comma_separted_values_count
    From table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
      REGEXP_COUNT ( REGEXP_REPLACE ( '-1,-2,-4,-6', '".*?"' ), ',' ) + 1
FROM
      DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `regexp_substr`.

```
select count(regexp_substr( '-1,-2,-4,-6','[^,]+', 1, level)) from dual
connect by regexp_substr( '-1,-2,-4,-6', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```